# How to return value as json in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

In my controller, Im returning a row like;

```
 $alarm= \DB::table('vwAlarmActionSummaryYFUserSite')
            ->where([['vwAlarmActionSummaryYFUserSite.yfUserID', '=', $yfUserID], ['vwAlarmActionSummaryYFUserSite.AlarmId', '=', $id]])->first();
```

When i do;

```
 var_dump( $alarm);
```

It gives;

```
object(stdClass)#249 (59) { ["AlarmId"]=> string(6) "246733" ["AlertTypeId"]=> string(2) "23" ["AlertTypeName"]=> string(20) "Missing Data - Sales" ["AlertTypeDescription"]=> string(20) "Brownout Sales Alarm" ["AlertSourceSystemId"]=> string(1) "1" ["AlertSourceSystemName"]=> string(7) "HD SIRA" ["AlertId"]=> string(7) "9957057" [
...........
```

I pass that to my `View` page like;

```
return view('alarms.ack', ['alarm' => $alarm, 'yfSessionId' => $yfSessionId]);
```

In the View I access properties like;

```
$alarm->SiteCode 
$alarm->AlarmId
```

Now, I get this exception;

```
 ErrorException
Cannot use object of type stdClass as array (View: /app/resources/views/alarms/ack.blade.php)
at CompilerEngine->handleViewException(object(FatalThrowableError), 0)
in PhpEngine.php (line 46)
at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/app/storage/framework/views/c593810096345df8c818851d1e61ae4bc523a3d4.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'alarm' => object(stdClass), 'yfSessionId' => 'abc'))
in CompilerEngine.php (line 59)
```

How can I overcome this?

Comment: But you are not using JSON anywhere. Are you sure the error is for that code only?

Comment: Quick fix:
$alarm['SiteCode ']
$alarm['AlarmId']

Comment: @SougataBose Im not sure. But in my view I access all properties like that..

Answer (score 0):

//Controller

```
 $data = return response()->json($alarm);
return view('alarms.ack', compact('data'));
```

//View

```
{!! $data->SiteCode !!}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 $value = return response()->json( array('result'=>array('data'=>$alarm)));
```

Comment: yup, this is the way you can return the array in json, $alarm is your whole data. now print $value this will return you json

Comment: Can you please tell me where that response() method comes from? Can you please edit my return statement?

Comment: response is the laravel inbuilt method...
see this link
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses